# How to take value from function which is in another function, as argument of final function

Tags: javascript

So I have 3 functions.
What i want to achieve is to take value from one function which is nested in parent function, and the pass it as the argument in third function.
And can this be achieved with closer, and how ?
Thanks so much.

```
function foo () {
    var rand  = 10;  
    function bar() {  
        return  {
            age:rand;
        }
    }
}

function addValue(arg) {
    console.log(bar());
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense, is this your actual problem before people show you how to strip the prototype (it is possible what you want, just not fun or intuitive IMO)? Try and write your actual, exact problem.

Comment: Did you mean "*…achieved with **closure***"? Yes.

Comment: @kabanus the code is really long, i am just asking for practical example, so I can wrap my head around new stuff. Also, if have posted the code, you would be review all of it, and tell me how everything is wrong, and I need to write it design patterns,  the other parts are redandant. So I really can't understand why did you down voted me and have that attitude, so rude.

Comment: @NemanjaD Fair enough, just make sure what you actually want to do is getting across in the question. For example `foo` could return `bar`, and then you could use it easily, with no hacky stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call as below

```
function foo () {
  var rand  = 10;  
  return function bar() {  
        return  {
            age:rand
         }
   }();
 }

function addValue(arg) {
   console.log(foo());
  }
```

Edited

```
 function foo (func) {
      var rand  = 10;  
      function bar() {  
          return  {
             age:rand
          }
      };
   //Do your stuff

     return eval(func+"()");
 }

 function addValue(arg) {
    console.log(foo("bar"));
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks, can it be achieved without return statement because i have another block of code executing inside foo() function ?

Comment: Put the return expression at the bottom of `foo`.

Comment: Check the edited code, you can write more chile function and pass the name as parameter in parent function "foo" to get the value from chile

Answer (score 0):

You can instead assign the function to the parent object and call it like this.

```js
function foo(){
 var rand = 10;
 this.bar = function(){
  return  {age: rand};
 }
}

var obj = new foo();
function addVal() {
 console.log(obj.bar());
}

addVal();
```